# How i can create Customer payment profile using CIM in Authrize,Net in C#?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

How i can create Customer payment profile using CIM in Authrize,Net in Asp.net C# mvc?
i am using AuthorizeNet api from NugetPackage in visual studio 2012.

Comment: Did you look at the SDK?  https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet.  You could also build an integration using XML using the API Reference http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference

Comment: I didn't use the above SDK, i am using AuthorizeNet API from Nuget package in visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little late on this, but I was having the same issue today.

It looks like the methods in the NuGet package on the object **CustomerGateway** you can use to create a customer payment profile are **AddCreditCard** or **AddECheckBankAccount** depending on your situation.

Example:

`CustomerGateway customerGateway = new CustomerGateway(apiLogin, transactionKey);
customerGateway.AddCreditCard(customerProfileId, cardNumber, month, year, cardCode, billingAddress);`